# Change the application title when go to particular pattern

Tags: sapui5

I want to change the application title (the title that appears on the tab up) when I go to a particular pattern.
I am setting the title in index.html. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is something like this:

**First controller**

```
onList: function() {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);   
        oRouter.navTo("list");  
    },
```

**Second controller**

```
    onInit: function() {
        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).getRoute("list").attachPatternMatched(this._onListRouteMatched, this);
    },

    _onListRouteMatched: function(oEvent){
        document.title = "test title";
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

For this use case, the framework added the `title`<sup>[1]</sup> property which can be assigned to each routing target object:

**In *manifest.json***

```js
"targets": {
  "target1": {
    "viewPath": "...",
    "viewName": "...",
    "title": "My Awesome Products!!"
  },
  //...
},
```

This alone, however, is not sufficient to update the title when the target is displaying. In order to do so, listen to the event `titleChanged`<sup>[[API]](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router/events/routePatternMatched)</sup> and get the parameter `"title"` from the event which should be then assigned to the `document.title` attribute:

**In *Component.js***

```js
init: function() {
  // ...
  this.getRouter().attachTitleChanged(this.onTitleChanged, this);
},

onTitleChanged: function(event) {
  document.title = event.getParameter("title"); // returns: "My Awesome Products!!"
},
```

You can even bind model data to the `title` property (e.g. for i18n), access previously used titles, and more. Take a look at the topic [**Using the title Property in Targets**](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1238d706b130433c9bd6b85cfb77cece).

---

### If Multiple Targets Are Assigned to Single Route

Usually, a route takes the title that is defined in its corresponding target. However, if multiple targets are assigned to a single route (e.g. to display master-detail views), the first defined title is taken into account. Though, if both targets have `title` defined, the route can declare explicitly from which target it should take the `title` which can be achieved by assigning the target name to the `titleTarget` property:

**In *manifest.json***

```json
"routes": {
  "myRoute": {
    "pattern": "myParticularPattern",
    "target": ["target1", "target2"],
    "titleTarget": "target2"
  }
},
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Available [since 1.42](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/65d64cbc974448ea508b3885db4c26e59416c944).

Answer (score -2):

A Quick way to change the application title:

window.document.title = "Your Title Name";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).